# Continuously extending a $p$-adic function to $\Bbb{Q}_p$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I am currently learning the basics of $p$-adic analysis, and its similarities (or dissimilarities) to $\Bbb{R}$. The Archimedean topology on $\Bbb{Z}$ is discrete, so there's nothing interesting in the continuity of a function $f:\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}$. However, one may ask the following question:

> Let $f:\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}$ be a continuous function w.r.t. the $p$-adic metric. Must there exists a continuous function $g:\Bbb{Q}_p\to\Bbb{Q}_p$ s.t. $g\restriction_{\Bbb{Z}} = f$?

Since $\Bbb{N}$ is dense in $\Bbb{Z}_p$, we can extend $f$ (uniquely) into $\Bbb{Z}_p$. But I see no reason for there to be an extension to $\Bbb{Q}_p$. Is there indeed a counterexample?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb Z_p$ is both open and closed in $\mathbb Q_p$. That implies you can take any continuous function $h$ on the complement of $\mathbb Z_p$ (e.g. any constant you like), and the function which maps $x\in \mathbb Z_p$ to $f(x)$ but every other $x$ to $h(x)$ is ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any function on $\mathbb Z_p$ can be easily extended to $\mathbb Q_p$, because $\mathbb Z_p$ is a clopen subset of $\mathbb Q_p$. In particular $f(x)\equiv 0$ for all $x\not\in\mathbb Z_p$ can get the job done.

However, it's not the case that any continuous function on $\mathbb Z$ can be extended to $\mathbb Z_p$, just like not every continuous function on $(0, 1)$ can be extended to $[0, 1]$.

For a concrete counter-example, consider the function $$f(x):=\nu_p(x-\frac{1}{1+p})$$

which is locally constant on $\mathbb Z$ hence continuous. However since $x_n=\sum_{i=0}^n (-p)^n$ converges to $\frac{1}{1+p}$, and $f(x_n)=n+1$ is not Cauchy, $f(x)$ cannot be continuously extended to be defined at $x=\frac{1}{1+p}$.

However, Lipschitz functions on $\mathbb Z$ can be easily extended to $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: The first paragraph is enough for the OP. But I do not agree with the rest of the answer. Because any  ($p$-adically) continuous function $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ can be easily extended to $\mathbb Z_p$, because $f$ is just a sequence $\{f(n)\}$ and hence it can be evaluated at any point of $\mathbb Z_p$ due to continuity, which is just $p$-adic completion of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @MAS $f$ is not "just a sequence", being $p$-adically continuous is a serious constraint. Again, this is the same as to say because $f(x)=1/x$ is continuous over $(0, 1)$, it can be evaluated at $x=0$ since $0$ is in the completion of $(0,1)$. Also, what's wrong with the example I gave?

Comment: I am talking about general theorem. Infact, the OP assumed $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb Z$ w.r.to p-adic metric and  also mentioned that one can extend $f$ to ring of $p$-adic integers from ordinary integers. The OP asked how to extend $f$ from the ring of p-adic integers to the field of p-adic numbers. Regarding the example, I don't know what is the point but certainly this is not correct

Comment: I have no idea which "general theorem" you are talking about. To my eyes, $f$ can be extended to $\mathbb Z_p$ was mentioned as a consequence, not a condition. In particular, your statement "any (p-adically) continuous function $f:\mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb Z$  can be easily extended to $\mathbb Z_p$" is simply false. The point of my example is to refute this false statement.

Comment: Please see the reason given in the question by OP.  This is a very basic fact. I  don't remember the exact result at this moment. But you can see [Theorem~5.15](http://swc-alpha.math.arizona.edu/video/2021/2021BellLecture5Notes.pdf). Besides that, see the bottom of page 21, Chapter II, of the book by Neal Koblitz.

Comment: @MAS The theorem in the linked slides explicitly says that such extension exists if and only if the function is **bounded** and **uniformly continuous**. OP does not state either of these conditions, just continuity, and the good counterexample in this answer illustrates that that is not enough.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, alright, thanks. I am voting up the answer